# ubuntu mail error coming every 30 min

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

```
501 Your domain does not seem to be valid. Could not find MX record for your domain.
501 5.6.0 Data format error

Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 501 Your domain does not seem to be valid. Could not find MX record for your domain.

Subject: Cron    [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
```

**the following error comes as mail every 30 min
please help
thanks in advance**

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what you want fixed here.

Answer (score 1):

I see several potential problems here.

1. The hostname of your server (`webwerks-G31M-ES2L`) is set to something other than a FQDN that you control.
2. The FQDN of your server has no MX records.
3. Your `/etc/aliases` file is forwarding emails somewhere invalid.
4. You have a standard PHP cron job running every 30 minutes but you aren't running a PHP website.
5. Your local mail server is configured to send mails that it shouldn't.
6. Your local mail server is claiming to be `webwerks-G31M-ES2L` rather than a FQDN.

What you should do to start is put lines in `/etc/aliases` file to send root's mail to you.

```
root: nik_hil@example.com
```

After that, work through the rest of that list and check each one to see if it's true.  You should find a file at `/etc/mailname` that tells Postfix what name to say it is when it talks to other mail servers.  That will help with `6.`.